# How do you use an alert to prompt for text in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func addPitcher(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Pitcher", message: "Enter Name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Finish", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Name"
        textField.secureTextEntry = false
    })
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    let newName : String = alert.textFields[0] as String
    println(newName)
}
```

This is the function in which we try and create an alert to prompt for a name. We get "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" error at the `alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in` line.

How do we fix this error, or more importantly, how do we retrieve the text from the field? Thank you for all help.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. I believe this to be just a bug from using the beta.

Comment: So did you find another way to input data using the alert or any other way? Or did you just give up on that part?

Comment: For now I just wrote this part in Objective-C and I will change it once it works in Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a textfield as a string. Blammo.

Also, get the value in the handler.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler:{ (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) in
            let textf = alert.textFields[0] as UITextField
            println(textf.text)
            }))
```

ps sometimes the error shown happens in a location different from the one given in the error message.